# How to call Pascal Script procedure if user does not select a (desktop icon) task in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to create a setup with Inno Setup which run a procedure, if user doesn't check *"Desktop icon"* checkbox.

I want just run a procedure if this condition is true (so that this checkbox is unchecked).

Can you help me please ?

```
[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: "Create a &desktop icon"; \
    GroupDescription: "Additional icons:";  

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\iaca"; Filename: "{app}\iconApp.ico"
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#myAppName} ({#version})"; Filename: "{app}\{#myExeName}"; \
    IconFilename: "{app}\iconApp.ico"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to run the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your procedure during an installation, test a `desktopicon` task state using [`WizardIsTaskSelected` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardistaskselected) in [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) and (not WizardIsTaskSelected('desktopicon')) then
  begin
    Log('"Create a desktop icon" task was not selected.');
    { Call your procedure here }
  end;
end;
```

*(The function is called `IsTaskSelected` in older versions of Inno Setup)*